# unable to telnet to imap on port 143 remotely

Tags: dovecot

I'm trying to get dovecot up and running on debian machine.

`telnet localhost 143` works fine. However, no dice when I try `telnet remote.example.com 143` from a remote machine. I get operation timed out.

I have `listen = *, ::` in my dovecot.conf file. `netstat -plutn` is this:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1228/mysqld.bin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3307/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4000/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      599/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3307/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4000/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      3307/master
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      4000/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2134/httpd.bin
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      599/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      3307/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2134/httpd.bin
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      4000/dovecot
<snip>
```

This is on an AWS machine. Not sure if there is a firewall or how I might open it.

Here is output of `dovecot -n`:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_privileged_group = mail
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Update, following advice on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11817296/1641112 it doesn't appear I have a firewall installed.

I have this problem even when trying to log into ip address for the remote machine directly.

Maybe amazon is blocking mail server ports?

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem was with me knowing next to nothing about amazon instance config. The server was part of an "security group". The group acts as a firewall and you have to open ports to allow access to them.

From the sidebar, go to Network & Security -> security groups -> check of the security group -> edit inbound rule and make your changes there.